# How to resize one div when its neighbouring div is done resizeing?

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I am trying to make a fluid grid website and now im facing a problem which a just cant seem to fix just using css. Obviously i'm doing something wrong, but i just cant find what.

Here's the thing: I have one column (div: left) and one body (div: right) displayed in-line. in stage one div left has a width of 180, and div right is growing till it reached 640px (like youtube). In stage two i want to make the column grow some more from 120px to 150 px, But when the column is growing div right gets pushed down, even though there is enough space. Im thinking it has something to do with the margin's technique ive been using but i cant find it, and dont know any alternatives i could use since im trying to do this without using java.

Here is my jsfiddle: which will show the problem clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/tomvisser/WcbYL/embedded/result/

I happy with all help i can get.

Thanks in advance.

```
<body>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="center">
    <div id="left">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "left"</div>
    <div id="right">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "right"</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

here is the css:

```
#left {
    float: left;
    height:400px;
    width: 150px;
    display:inline;
    background-color:#F00;
}

#right {
    margin-left:150px;
    background-color: #6F0 ;
    height:400px;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 650px) {
.gridContainer {}

#right {
    margin-left:0px;
    width:500px;
    float:right;
    display:inline;
}
#left {
    margin-left:0px;
    float: right;
    width:100%;
    margin-right:500px; 
}
```

Comment: I find that your description is quite confusing >.< Anyway from what I understand so far, you'd like to have the green div to stay at the same level as the red div instead of getting pushed down. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's the margin pushing it down. Not sure what you're asking exactly but I can probably bet you're looking to give the 2 divs the `max-width` property.

So for step 2 (the media query?), delete the margins and try doing something like:

`max-width: 180px;`

for the left column.

This is the code I edited in your media query block:

```
#right {
    margin-left:0px;
    width:500px;
    float:right;
    display:inline;
}
#left {
    margin-left:0px;
    float: right;
    max-width:180px;
}
```

Although do you have them floating right on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i tried your code and find a solution for you.Hope it will help for you.Here i am
assuming the total width of a page is 1024px.

**HTML code**

```
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="center">
    <div id="right">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "right"</div>
    <div id="left">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "left"</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css" >
#left {
    height:400px;
    background-color:#F00;
    width:512px;
}
#right {
    background-color: #6F0 ;
    height:400px;
    float:right;
    width:512px;
}
</style>
```

Here i am giving width 512px to each div because i am assuming that total width of page
is 1024px.If you want to increase the width of left by 12 px means 512px + 12px = 524px
then you need to decrease 12px from div right width because width cannot be more
then total width of page i.e 1024px.After decreasing it will become 500px and again 
524px + 500px = 1024px.In that case your right div will not push down.
Hope you understand and will work for you.